# How to manipulate & resize images in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `The Public Disk` which is local driver. I create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public` using this given command `php artisan storage:link`. I didn't change anything as mentioned in laravel filesystem documentation. But i'm not able to view the image with `asset` helper. `File_path` is storing in database but still images are broken.

**Controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'file'  => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $slide = new Slider();
    $slide->title       = $request->title;
    $slide->description = $request->description;

    //uploading image
    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $file   = $request->file('file');

        $slide->file_name = str_random(40) . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $slide->file_size = $file->getClientSize();
        $slide->file_mime = $file->getClientMimeType();
        $slide->file_path = $file->storeAs('public', $slide->file_name);
    }

    $slide->status    = $request->status;
    $slide->save();

    return redirect()->route('slider.index')->with('success', 'Done');
}
```

I'm using `storeAs` method, which receives the path, the file name.

**Database:**
[image]

**View:**

`<td><img src="{{ asset($slide->file_path) }}" class="content" width="25"></td>`

`StoreAs` method returns the path which is `public/filename.jpg` and images store into `public/storage` folder. How do i view the images?

Comment: Why not change `public` to `public/storage`?

Comment: I didn't get you, path is already defined which is `public` to `public/storage`.

Comment: I meant this `$file->storeAs('public'` you mentioned that `StoreAs` returns `public/filename.jpg` so why not try and change ``$file->storeAs('public'` to `$file->storeAs('public/storage'` ?

Comment: Then what's the purpose of symbolic link? It's not possible.

Comment: If i do this then `storeAs` method will make one more folder e.g `public/storage/storage`

Comment: `If you would not like a file name to be automatically assigned to your stored file, you may use the storeAs method, which receives the path, the file name, and the (optional) disk as its arguments:` I don't think `storeAs` will generate a directory it would problably return an error if the directory doesn't exists.

Comment: I did it, but didn't return an error and create a directory like this; `public/storage/storage` to `storage/app/public/storage`.

Comment: Can't you just directly point to "public/storage/filename.png" in your assets folder instead of using the path returned by the `storeAs` function? `{{ asset("public/storage/image.png") }}`

Comment: Yes it's working, if i do this `{{ asset('storage' . $file_name) }}`, then what's the purpose of `file_path` which is storing in database. How do i accessible `file_path`?

Comment: @user3740316 whats the length of the column ```file_path``` in database?

Comment: For the file path you can update it to save the correct path, maybe doing a str_replace to change public/ to public/storage instead. I'm sure there's a better way to approach that problem though. I haven't used symbolic link and my uploads always go to a custom directory so I can't really help you on that.

Comment: @Adnan Mumtaz the length is 191.

Comment: @hungrykoala cheers up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public and S3 storages support the `url` method that you can use to get the correct URL for the image

```
<td><img src="{{ Storage::url($slide->file_path) }}" class="content" width="25"></td>
```

Comment: Alright, if you see above the `database`, `file_path` has public directory, `Storage::url($slide->file_path)`, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You should add storage prefix to your asset:

```
<td><img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $slide->file_path) }}" class="content" width="25"></td>
```

Comment: No, images are broken.